# return first {Key, Value} from Map where Predicate is true

Tags: erlang

The more formal definition of problem is

> Write a function map_search_pred(Map, Pred) that returns the first
>   element {Key,Value} in the map for which Pred(Key, Value) is true.

My attempt, looks like

```
map_search_pred(Map, Pred)  ->
  M = [{Key, Value} || {Key, Value} <- maps:to_list(Map), Pred(Key, Value) =:= true],
  case length(M) of
    0 -> {};
    _ -> lists:nth(1, M)
  end.
```

When I run this, I get correct answer

```
1> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{}
2> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{1 => 1, 2 => 2}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{1,1}
3> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{1 => 1, 2 => 3}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{1,1}
4> lib_misc:map_search_pred(#{1 => 2, 2 => 2}, fun(X, Y) -> X =:= Y end).
{2,2}
5>
```

**Problem?**
The problem is efficiency.
It uses list comprehension and runs for all the elements in the list. The better solution would be to return after the first match.

As a beginner to language, I do not know a better idiomatic way to solve this, so looking for better ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could walk the list yourself and return as soon as you find an element for which `Pred(Key, Value)` is true:

```
map_search_pred(Map, Pred) when is_map(Map) ->
    map_search_pred(maps:to_list(Map), Pred);
map_search_pred([], _) ->
    error;
map_search_pred([{Key,Value}=H|T], Pred)  ->
    case Pred(Key, Value) of
        true ->
            {ok, H};
        false ->
            map_search_pred(T, Pred)
    end.
```